# Taylor series for function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

In my textbook taylor series for function of two variable has been written like this:

$$ f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)h+f_y(a,b)k+\frac 1 2 (f_{xx}(a,b)h^2+ 2hkf_{xy}(a,b)+f_{yy}(a,b)k^2)+h^2+k^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}B(h,k) $$

in which $B(h,k)$ is a bounded function around the center.

My question is where did $(h^2+k^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ come from ?

why is $B(h,k)$ bounded and what does it mean in this context that $B(h,k)$ is bounded?

in my textbook doesn't mention anything about these.
Can someone please explain these

Comment: In polar coordinates, $(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}=r^3$. Compare to the univariate formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single variable function $f$, the Taylor polynomial $T_nf$ of degree $n$ has the property that

$f(x_0+h)=T_nf(x_0;h)+\vert h\vert^{n+1} B_n(h)$ with $B_n$ bounded. This essentially says that $f$ is approximately equal to the Taylor polynomial plus some remainder which goes to 0 very quickly as $h\to0$. To be specific, it goes to $0$ quicker than $h^n$. This is guaranteed by the boundedness of $B_n$: The remainder is $h^{n+1}$ (so of higher order than $h^n$) multiplied by something bounded, so it doesn't slow down the speed with which the remainder goes to 0.

This can be generalized to multi-variable functions by replacing $h$ with the vector $\vec h=(h_1,\dots,h_n)$ (or in 2d, you could also name the components $(h,k)$) and $\vert h\vert$ with the norm $\vert \vec h\vert=\sqrt{h_1^2+\dots+h_n^2}$, or in 2d with $\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$. What it should say to actually capture the intuition is something like this:

$f(\vec a+\vec h)=T_2f(\vec a;\vec h)+\vert\vec h\vert^{2+1} B_2(\vec h)$, where $\vec a=(a,b),~\vec h(=h,k)$ and where $T_2f$ is just all the terms I've suppressed in this notation (so the actual Taylor polynomial itself). Now just plug in $\vert \vec h\vert=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ and you'll see where the $(\dots)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ comes from.

Comment: @ Vercassivelaunos, with $B_n(h) $ does it mean this :$$\frac{M}{(n+1)!}$$ and if it's the case this function doesn't depend on h why they write it as $B_n(h) $ ?

Comment: @Nima No, $B_n$ depends on $h$. Essentially, $B_n(h)=\frac{f(x_0+h)-T_nf(x_0;h)}{\vert h\vert^{n+1}}$. Since $f$ can be any sufficiently differentiable function, while $T_nf$ is a polynomial, $B_n$ has to depend on $h$. For instance, if $f(x)=\exp(x)$, then $\exp(0+h)=1+h+h^2\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{h^{k-2}}{k!}$. Here, $1+h$ is $T_1\exp$, and the series at the end is $B_n$. You can see that it's not a constant.

Comment: Thank you very much can you please explain that what is the relation between lagrange remainder :$$\frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$$ and that form of remainder $B_n(h)$? And another thing is that I think that $ e^{h+0} = 1+h+\frac{h^2}{2!}+...$ but in your comment I don't understand why $e^{h+0} = 1+h+h^2 +...$ Thank you again for helping

Comment: And can you please say what is called $B_n(h)$? because every place I look at there is information about lagrange remainder I want to study more on this

Comment: @Nima In op's post, the remainder is not specified, so it gets no special name. It just describes the behavior of all the different remainder formulas close to $x_0$. There are more explicit formulas as well, like the Lagrange remainder. In the version you've given, they used other variables, though. With the change of variables $a\to x_0,~x-a\to h$ it becomes $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}h^{n+1}$. Now it's more easily visible that the fraction on the left is $B_n$. Keep in mind that $\xi$ depends on $h$, so this is not constant.

Comment: And about the exponential function: I didn't write that it's $1+h+h^2+\dots$. The $h^2$ is multiplied by a series whose first term is $1/2!$, so if you carry out the multiplication you get $1+h+h^2/2!+\dots$ the way it's supposed to be.